# Does $k=9018009$ have a friend?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

(Note: This question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/251982).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $x$.  For example, $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12$ and $\sigma(28)=1+2+4+7+14+28=56$.

Denote the *abundancy index* $I$ of $x$ by
$$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}.$$

If a positive integer $y$ is one of at least two solutions of
$$I(y)=\frac{a}{b}$$
for a given rational number $a/b$, then $y$ is called a [*friendly number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number).

Here is a formal definition:

**DEFINITION**. Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct positive integers.  If $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equation $I(x)=I(y)$ then $(x,y)$ is called a *friendly pair*.  Each member of the pair is called a *friendly number*.  (In other words, $x$ is a *friend* of $y$, and $y$ is also a *friend* of $x$.)  A number which is *not* friendly is called a [*solitary number*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html).

Here is my question:

> Does $k=9018009$ have a friend?

Comment: I think that the formal terminology is *amicable numbers* (rather than *friendly pair*).

Comment: Amicable numbers are different.

Comment: The abundancy index of $9018009$ is $\frac{22021}{11011}$, which is perilously close to $2$,if that matters.

Comment: @barakmanos No, Aravind is right. Friendly numbers are $x$ and $y$ such that $\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}=\frac{\sigma(y)}{y}$ while amicable numbers are such that $\sigma(x)-x=y$ and $\sigma(y)-y=x$.

Comment: Such questions are often impossible to answer unless a search among small candidates is lucky to find the first friend. As an example, the question "does $k=10$ have a friend?" is an open problem. Do you have any reason to think your question is easier?

Comment: Since $9018009 = 3003^2$, is it known that perfect squares are solitary or something?

Comment: Some even squares are known to be friendly, and therefore not solitary.  On the other hand, I believe that nobody has found a friendly odd square yet.  It is conjectured that all odd squares are solitary, although I could not recall a reference offhand.

Comment: OK, why did you not mention that in the question? I see from [another post by you (Can distinct odd perfect numbers $N = {p^k}{m^2}$ share the same Euler factor $p^k$?)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522326/) that $$I(26334^2)=\frac{127}{36}=I(8640)$$ and other friends from this "friendly club" are given there. So $26334^2=693479556$ is a square that has friends. In that same post you also mention this conjecture that _odd_ squares cannot be friendly. By the way, why are you specifically interested in $9018009$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, $9018009 = {3003}^2$ is a factor of the Descartes spoof $198585576189$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes_number)).

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This was copied and pasted from an answer (now deleted) to this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251982).)

> > **MOTIVATION**

As mentioned in my comment last September $12$, $2016$ to the [linked MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1922297),
$$9018009 = {3003}^2$$
is a factor of the [Descartes spoof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes_number) $198585576189$.

Note that we can write a spoof as
$$n = km$$
where $k > 1$, $m > 1$, $m \nmid k$ such that
$$\sigma(k)\cdot\left(m + 1\right) = 2n = 2km,$$
where $k$ is an odd square and $m$ is the quasi-Euler prime.

(Note that $22021 = m < k = 9018009$ for the Descartes spoof $198585576189$.)

Now, we can rewrite
$$\sigma(k)\cdot\left(m + 1\right) = 2n = 2km$$
as
$$\sigma(k) = {m}\cdot\left(2k - \sigma(k)\right),$$
$$\dfrac{\sigma(k)}{m} = 2k - \sigma(k),$$
and
$$2k = \left(m + 1\right)\cdot\left(2k - \sigma(k)\right),$$
so that
$$\gcd\left(k, \sigma(k)\right) = \gcd\bigg((1/2)\cdot\left(m + 1\right)\cdot\left(2k - \sigma(k)\right), {m}\cdot\left(2k - \sigma(k)\right)\bigg) = 2k - \sigma(k).$$

We therefore have the following lemma:

> **LEMMA**
>   Let $n = km > 1$ be a spoof.  Then
>   $$\gcd\left(k, \sigma(k)\right) = 2k - \sigma(k) = \dfrac{\sigma(k)}{m}.$$

The following theorem follows from this lemma:

> **THEOREM**
>   Let $n = km > 1$ be a Descartes spoof.  Then $k > 1$ is almost perfect and solitary if and only if $k < m$.

**PROOF**
The details of the proof are in pages $6$ to $7$ of this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03860v4.pdf).

Finally, we have the following conjecture:

> **CONJECTURE**
>   ${3003}^2 = {3^2}\cdot{7^2}\cdot{{11}^2}\cdot{{13}^2} = 9018009$ is not solitary.

Hence, my original inquiry in this MO question.

> > **CONTEXT**

My approach to spoofs is similar to that for odd perfect numbers (as initiated in this [M. Sc. thesis, pages 98 to 118](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1450v2.pdf)).  As [Nielsen](https://mathoverflow.net/u/3199) has pointed out to me, "the only [case] when results on [spoofs] do not carry over to odd perfect numbers (and vice-versa?) is when the results depend on previous computational results (and assumptions?) on spoofs [reciprocally, odd perfect numbers?]".  Indeed, the inequality $m^1 < k$ for the lone Descartes spoof "corresponds" to the inequality $q^k < n^2$ (see this [paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html)) where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, if we "*pretend* that $m$ is *prime*".