# Who is credited with the conjecture that all odd squares are solitary?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, conjectures, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of the positive integer $x$.  For example, $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12$ and $\sigma(28)=1+2+4+7+14+28=56$.

Denote the *abundancy index* $I$ of $x$ by
$$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}.$$

If a positive integer $y$ is one of at least two solutions of
$$I(y)=\frac{a}{b}$$
for a given rational number $a/b$, then $y$ is called a [*friendly number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number).

Here is a formal definition:

**DEFINITION**. Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct positive integers.  If $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equation $I(x)=I(y)$ then $(x,y)$ is called a *friendly pair*.  Each member of the pair is called a *friendly number*.  (In other words, $x$ is a *friend* of $y$, and $y$ is also a *friend* of $x$.)  A number which is *not* friendly is called a [*solitary number*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html).

Checking the first few odd squares $N$ gives us $\gcd(N,\sigma(N))=1$, which by Greening's Theorem means that such $N$ are solitary.  Since Greening's Theorem that

> **$\gcd(N,\sigma(N))=1$ implies that $N$ is solitary.**

is sufficient (but not necessary), "it's easy to find odd squares for which $\gcd(n, \sigma(n))$ is not equal to $1$; e.g. if  $n = {21}^2 = 441$  then $\gcd(n, \sigma(n)) = 3$.  But $441$ is solitary." **(Dean Hickerson, personal communication via e-mail, Mar. 12, 2011)**

Here is my question:

> **Who is credited with the conjecture that all odd squares are solitary?**

Comment: This was inspired by comments to your other question [Does $k=9018009$ have a friend?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922297/).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, indeed!  Thanks for pointing that out.  Nonetheless, the question is interesting in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

In an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922297/does-k-9018009-have-a-friend/1965454#1965454) to a related MSE question (as hinted by [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/70134) in the comments), it is conjectured that $9018009 = {3003}^2$ is not solitary.

*It remains to find a friend of $9018009$, or to prove that none exists.*